# Pub/Sub Broker Subscriber Interface

Tags: concurrency, go

I'm working to build out a `Subscriber` interface for handling at-least-once messaging semantics, so I can produce different brokers. Here's my interface thus far:

```
// AtLeastOnceSubscriber defines the interface for a subscriber with at-least-
// once message delivery semantics
type AtLeastOnceSubscriber interface {
    // Start creates a channel to the message broker for receiving messages
    Start(ctx context.Context) (<-chan AtLeastOnceMessage, <-chan error)
    // AckMessage will delete the given message from its respective message queue
    AckMessage(ctx context.Context, messageID string) error
    // ExtendAckDeadline will postpone resending the given in-flight message for
    // the specified duration
    ExtendAckDeadline(ctx context.Context, messageID string, newDuration time.Duration) error
}

// AtLeastOnceMessage contains the payload for a message with at-least-once
// delivery semantics
type AtLeastOnceMessage interface {
    // MessageID returns the ID that uniquely identifies this message. You can use
    // this to Ack or extend the ack deadline from the Subscriber
    MessageID() string
    // Message returns the payload from the message
    Message() []byte
    // ExtendAckDeadline extends the duration that a message can remain in-flight
    // before it will get added back to the message queue for redelivery. Call
    // this if processing the message will take longer than the existing time window.
    ExtendAckDeadline(time.Duration) error
    // Ack will signal to the message broker that this given message has been
    // processed and can be deleted
    Ack() error
}
```

A simple example implementation:

```
func (s *someConcreteImplementation) Start(ctx context.Context) (<-chan AtLeastOnceMessage, <- chan error) {
    iChan := make(chan AtLeastOnceMessage)
    eChan := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        defer close(iChan)
        defer close(eChan)
        for {
            select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    // do stuff to try to gracefully terminate
                    return
                default:
                    msg, err := s.getSomeThing()
                    if err != nil {
                        eChan <- err
                    } else {
                        iChan <- msg
                    }
            }
        }
    }()
    return iChan, eChan
}
```

A dumb example demonstration of using this interface:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel()
defer cancel()
c, e := myConcreteSubscriberImplementation.Start(ctx)
for {
    select {
        case msg, ok := <- c:
            if !ok {
                return // the channel has been closed
            }
            // .. do something with msg
        case err := <- e:
            fmt.Println(err)
            cancel() // probably do better stuff than this in the real world
    }
}
```

#### My main question

I've received a recommendation that my interface should expose a `Stop()` function to allow the caller to close the channel, but I feel like this is redundant because of the passed in context, which does the exact same thing.

Or, is this just a bad design?

Comment: As-is this isn't a great question for Code Review; we require real code that we can actually review. Maybe something makes sense in one case but not another, or we might suggest a new approach entirely. I'm voting to close for that reason, but if you have a specific example of real code I'd happily vote to re-open.

Comment: gotcha. I'm happy to close this and either rephrase for SO or post a concrete code review.

Comment: No need to close it yourself; it'll probably get closed on its own anyway. If you have the concrete code then please edit the question and include it, then @ me so I can retract my close vote :)

Comment: heeeey @Dannnno, I've updated my question: does it pass muster? I'm not interested just yet in any concrete implementation -- just my interface design. Hopefully that's something that can generate criticism here.

Comment: Yes it does :) Looks like at least 5 of us agreed.